# Unable to connect with a google backend from Wix

Tags: javascript, frontend, velo

I have built an ML backend and deployed it over google cloud. When I call the backend from a wix front-end form with some data, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I'm using the following code to perform this on a button click.

```
export function button1_click(event) {
 // This function was added from the Properties & Events panel. To learn more, visit http://wix.to/UcBnC-4
 // Add your code for this event here: 
 var data = $w("#textBox1").value;
 
 var raw = JSON.stringify({"data":data});
 var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
        };
 var url = "https://url-for-google-webapp" 
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to this was to define the URL inside `onReady()` and save it local storage

```
import {local} from 'wix-storage';

$w.onReady(function () {
    local.setItem("url", "https://the-url-you-want-to-visit")
});
```

And then inside `button1_click(event)` method retreive the set variable:

```
export function button1_click(event) {
 ...
 var url = local.getItem("url")
 fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```